# Any way to see if a COM server is already running?

Tags: c#, com

I have a COM server running in its own .exe that provides an optional interface. If the user hasn't started the program, I don't want to start it for them. Unfortunately it *does* start automatically if I use the following code:

```
Type typ = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(prog_id);
server = (IMyServer)Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
```

I'm already using `Process.GetProcessesByName` to see if the executable is running, but there are cases where the COM connection can't be made even if the process is detected. Is there a more direct method to prevent it from starting the server?

Comment: Have you looked at the ROT (IRunningObjectTable)? CoGetObject might also works (BIND_OPTS has BIND_JUSTTESTEXISTENCE, not always supported)

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried looking at the ROT but my process isn't listed, even when it has an actual connection to another process.

Comment: Could that be a 32 vs 64-bit or UAC/rights issue?